# Amazon S3 POST, event when done?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, http-post, dom-events

I'm using Amazon S3 with a simple project, when the user uploads a file, I first use an `XMLHTTPRequest` to send the details to my database, then trigger the form POST that uploads the file straight to S3.

What I can't quite work out though is how to tell when the upload is done so I can update the display properly (I'm cheating at the moment and just updating the display once it's saved in the database, you can barely tell for small uploads, but obviously a problem in the long run.)

The S3 server appears to "cancel navigation" once the upload is complete, so the page doesn't reload - are there any events that are fired that I can use to detect when the upload is complete?

EDIT: I'm using the form code from here http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html just added an onsubmit to the form that fires the XMLHTTPRequest to my own server before the form gets posted to amazon.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Amazon S3 will redirect to the url specified in the `success_action_redirect` field or if that's not specified, it returns an empty document with the status code specified in `success_action_status`.

> On completion of the POST, the user is redirected to the location that you specified in the success_action_redirect field. If Amazon S3 cannot interpret the URL, it ignores the success_action_redirect field.
>
> If success_action_redirect is not specified, Amazon S3 returns the empty document type specified in the success_action_status field.
>
> If the POST fails, Amazon S3 displays an error and does not provide a redirect.

See the [AWS docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?HTTPPOSTForms.html) for more details.

Comment: Lovely, thanks Geoff - I had noticed the success_action_redirect in the docs, but read `The redirect field name is deprecated and support for the redirect field name will be removed in the future.` Now that you've made me read it again, I realise that it's not the whole feature that is deprecated, but just the field called `redirect` for doing it (must read slower!). This should do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @MalphasWats - yes, I noticed that in the docs too. At a glance, it's easy to misinterpret what they mean.

Comment: @MalphasWats - You know you need to manually assign the bounty... just saying... ;-)

Comment: ha, sorry Geoff, I didn't realise that! I thought it did it automagically when I selected an answer :) Done now, thank you!

Comment: @MalphasWats - Cool. No Problem. I've seen lots of comments like mine on SO. Its seems that this should be made clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 won't trigger any kind of event, but your XMLHTTPRequest code should be able to trigger a callback  when S3 returns an HTTP 200 status code.

If S3 isn't returning a successful response code, it's quite possible that S3 doesn't know that your upload is complete. Are you sending a `Content-Length` header as part of your request?

Comment: not that I'm aware of - I'm using a simple POST form to send a file, so the XMLHTTPRequest doesn't communicate at all with Amazon, it sends the details to my server then just triggers the form.submit() to the S3 bucket - I don't think there's an easy way to add the content-length header to the form?