# Getting S3 Response code (Only the HTTP code like 200,300,400,403,500 Etc) while saving file using S3a in pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the HTTP code and store in RDS table for later analysis of pyspark job which will save the file as AVRO format to S3 using S3a. Once the file is saved I know that there will be return status code from S3 but I am not sure how to record that in Code. please find the snippet of the code.

```
def s3_load(df, row):
    df.write.\
       format("com.databricks.spark.avro").\
       save("s3a://Test-" + row["PARTNER"].lower() + "/" + row["TABLE_NAME"] + "/" +
            datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

In the above code i would like the o get the return as status code.
Note:I am able to save the file in S3 as AVRO format.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar concept discussed in this question, getting a status code of a library or function that wraps an s3 API: [Amazon S3 POST, event when done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145160/amazon-s3-post-event-when-done)

---

Ultimately, if databricks is the library handling the upload, the resulting response code from the `df.write.save(...)` function call would be found somewhere in the result of the databricks function call.

Databricks supports `s3` and `s3a` as target destinations for saving files ([as shown in their docs here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html#s3)), but it doesn't appear that databricks surfaces the response code from underlying operations here (maybe they do, I couldn't find it in any of the docs).

**A few options for moving forward:**

- Assuming databricks will throw "some" sort of error for that upload, a simple `try`/`except` will allow you to properly catch this (although any non-databricks level errors would still pass).
- On AWS, s3 bucket uploads are an event source that can be used as a trigger for other operations like invoking an AWS Lambda, which you can use to call an arbitrary cloud hosted function. Lots of info available on [what this architecture would look like in this tutorial.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)
- Depending on the need for parallel uploading, you can rewrite your small upload function using `boto3`, the official AWS python library. Discussion on how to handle those error/response codes [discussed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580092/boto3-verify-if-the-file-has-been-uploaded-using-upload-file)
- Databricks also seems to have audit logging capabilities somewhere in their [enterprise offering.](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs.html)

Comment: Thanks, I used Try/Except and now I am able to at least find my job is successful or not.